# List of data and an empty dictionary keys - Is there a way to assign the data sequentially to the dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax, sqlalchemy, orm

i have a dictionary content as below

```
contentDict = {
            "Prefecture": "",
            "Total List Number": "",
            "Title": "",
            "Event Validity": "",
            "Available Period": "",
            "Available StartDate": "",
            "End Date": "",
            "Last Updated": "",
            "mainText": "",
            "Location Tag": "",
            "Event Tag": "",
            "Main Image URL": "",
            "innerWebSiteURL": "",
            "ListLink": ""
        }
```

and a list of contents of the same length.

is there a way to assign each content of an list sequentially to the dictionary

i tried using zip() but failed miserably

The dictionary would need to be ordered in the sequence specified because i would like to add it to a mysql database in the order provided..

the end GOAL is to use to_sql() method to put the dictionary into the MySQL database

I initially coded without the MySQL in mind and later was told to use ORM to_SQL method to transfer the data..

any hints or guide would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, assuming your list is **contentList**,

```
contentList = [i for i in range(14)]
```

one thing would be looping through keys:

```
for i,k in enumerate(contentDict):
    contentDict[k] = contentList[i]
```

Or 'pythonically':

```
contentDict = {k:contentList[i] for i,k in enumerate(contentDict)}
```

Comment: thanks for the info, much appreciated. Im just alittle curious. how do you learn pythonical expressions. i find them beautiful... the shortest way to express a code... but i never seem to find them anywhere to learn... or is it from just repeated experience

Comment: another pythonic option: `newDict = dict(zip(contentDict.keys(), contentList))`